# Does "anyone" mean "any random person"?

Tags: meaning, pronouns

Since my question actually is about stating the correct words, it needs to communicate by an example.
Suppose I am elected as the president of America now. One day, my mother comes and knocks my door and says "Hey! Our neighbour is here to see you and spend some time with you. Come out!".
Since I think I am a very important person, I get angry, and I want to convey to my mom that she must not allow everyone to visit me. What should I say?
I need something like this in meaning:

> I don't want *any random person* to be able to see me, mom.

I myself have come to this:

> I don't want *anyone* to be able to see me.

And I know it's wrong. (just in case to be more clear)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"I don't want just anyone to be able to see me." The use of *just* emphasises the idea of *anyone that is not special*